# Multiple 'or' condition in Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

I have a little code issue and it works with IDLE and not with Eclipse, can I write this :

```
if  fields[9] != ('A' or 'D' or 'E' or 'N' or 'R'):
```

instead of this :

```
if  fields[9] != 'A' and fields[9] != 'D' and fields[9] != 'E' and fields[9] != 'N' and fields[9] != 'R':
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `not in` and a sequence:

```
if fields[9] not in ('A', 'D', 'E', 'N', 'R'):
```

which tests against a tuple, which Python will conveniently and efficiently store as one constant. You could also use a set literal:

```
if fields[9] not in {'A', 'D', 'E', 'N', 'R'}:
```

but only more recent versions of Python ([Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations) and newer) will recognise this as an immutable constant. This is the fastest option for newer code.

Because this is one character, you could even use a string:

```
if fields[9] not in 'ADENR':
```

Answer (score 15):

You want the `in` operator:

```
if fields[9] not in 'ADENR':
    ...
```

Or, you could use `any`:

```
if not any(fields[9] == c for c in 'ADENR'):
    ...
```

Or, alternatively, `all`, which may have a bit more of the same form as the original:

```
if all(fields[9] != c for c in 'ADENR'):
    ...
```

---

As an aside:

```
if x != ('A' or 'B' or 'C'):
```

is really the same thing as saying:

```
if x != 'A':
```

because `'A' or 'B' or 'C'` evaluates to `'A'` (Try it!).  The reason is because with `or`, python will return the first "non-falsey" value (or the last one if they're all falsey).  Since non-empty strings are non-falsey, the first one gets returned.