# Remove different string elements

Tags: python, list

I've got a list of string elements and I'd like to remove 3 values which are `'English'`, `'english'`, and `'French'`.

I've tried the following code but the operation doesn't work:

```
x = ['English','english','French','Dutch','Spanish','Japenese','Italian',]
list = np.random.choice(x,100)
y = [elem for elem in list if elem !='English' or elem !='english' or elem !='French']
```

The final result that I'd like to will be a list without the string values `'English'`, `'english'`, and `'French'`.

Comment: ˋorˋ means *all* conditions must be false for the entire condition to be false. There is no string for which this is satisfied - e.g. „English“ will trigger the first condition, but both of the others accept it.

Comment: Related: [Multiple 'or' condition in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22304500/4518341)

Comment: What does `np.random.choice` have to do with the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Given `elem = 'English'`, `elem !='English' or elem !='english'` is `True` because although `elem !='English'` is False, `elem !='english'` is True. That's how `or` works.

Comment: So, what solution do you propose for this case please

Answer (score 1):

You want `and`, not `or`.

```
>>> x = ['English', 'english', 'French', 'Dutch', 'Spanish', 'Japenese', 'Italian']
>>> [i for i in x if i != 'English' and i != 'english' and i != 'French']
['Dutch', 'Spanish', 'Japenese', 'Italian']
```

That said, you could do this more easily with `not in`:

```
>>> [i for i in x if i not in ['English', 'english', 'French']]
['Dutch', 'Spanish', 'Japenese', 'Italian']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option... Just

```
def remove(elm,lst):
    idxs = []
    for n,k in enumerate(lst):
        if(k == elm):
            idxs.append(n)
    for n,k in enumerate(idxs):
        del(lst[k-n])

x = ['English','english','French','Dutch','Spanish','Japenese','Italian',]
for k in ["english","English","French"]:
    remove(k,x)
print(x) # ['Dutch', 'Spanish', 'Japenese', 'Italian']
```