# 'or' boolean operation appearing faulty when comparing a string to two cases

Tags: python, loops, boolean, iteration, zip

I have a simple code below that doesn't seem to output the expected result. The code only prints `yup` once even though I expect the code to print `yup` three times since that boolean expression will be true three times during the entire for loop iteration. Any advice on how to change my bool expression so that the loop prints `yup` three times?

```
a1=['555','666','777',66]
b1=['999','888','333',66]

for a,b in zip(a1,b1):
    if a == ('555'  or  '666' or 66):
        print('yup')
```

Comment: So many duplicates. TLDR: That is the same as a == ‘555’. Hint: a == b or a == c or a == d (or) a in (b, c, d).

Comment: Yup, or you could also use a in (b, c ,d)

Comment: The “why”: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870378/python-or-operator-weird-behavior/13870419, the “fix”: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22304500/2864740 (just remove the ‘not’ in this case), and the _inverse_ case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/2864740

Comment: @user2864740 sorry im new to stack and didnt do my search thoroughly — should this post be deleted or left as is? My problem has been solved.

Comment: It’s your call. I would consider a vote to close it with a duplicate that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this helps highlight your problem

```
x = ('555'  or  '666' or 66)
print(x)
a1=['555','666','777',66]
for a in a1:
    if a == x:
       print("yup")
```

the correct check is

either

```
if a in ('555'  or  '666' or 66)
```

or

```
if a == '555' or a == '666' or a == 66
```