# If loop with multiple conditions still executing when one condition is not met

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm making a roman numeral to integer converter. In the code below, you will see the function `math_logic`. When I give the input `CCC`, the program should  skip the `if` statements and `elif` statements (because of the keyword `and`) and go right to the `else` statement since only one of the two conditions are met. The `else` statement should return a dictionary value using parameter `char_0` as the key. However, the program will run the code inside the second `elif` statement and return `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'` as the error.

I'm not sure why this is happening. You can put a debug point at line 38 and step into 4 times to get to the issue I'm having.

Please see code below

```
romanToIntDictionary = {
    "I": 1,
    "V": 5,
    "X": 10,
    "L": 50,
    "C": 100,
    "D": 500,
    "M": 1000
}

subtraction_happened = [
    4,
    9,
    40,
    90,
    400,
    900
]


def convert_roman_to_int(string, checker_state):
    characters_left = len(string)
    character_list = []
    total = 0
    if checker_state:
        print("What you entered is a valid roman numeral.")
        for character in string:
            character_list.append(character)
        while characters_left > 1:
            did_i_sub = False
            for item in subtraction_happened:
                if (not did_i_sub) and (item == math_logic(character_list[0], character_list[1], romanToIntDictionary)): #the order of multiple conditions matters
                    total = total + math_logic(character_list[0], character_list[1], romanToIntDictionary)
                    characters_left -= 2
                    character_list.pop(0)
                    character_list.pop(0)
                    did_i_sub = True
            if not did_i_sub:
                total = total + math_logic(character_list[0], character_list[1], romanToIntDictionary)
                characters_left -= 1
                character_list.pop(0)
        while characters_left == 1:
            total = total + romanToIntDictionary[character_list[0]]
            characters_left -= 1
            character_list.pop(0)
        print(total)
    if not checker_state:
        print("What you entered is not a roman numeral.")


def math_logic(char_0, char_1, r_to_i_dict):
    if (char_0 == "I") and (char_1 == "V" or "X"):
        if char_1 == "V":
            return 4
        elif char_1 == "X":
            return 9
    elif (char_1 == "L" or "C") and (char_0 == "X"):
        if char_1 == "L":
            return 40
        elif char_1 == "C":
            return 90
    elif (char_1 == "D" or "M") and (char_0 == "C"):
        if char_1 == "D":
            return 400
        elif char_1 == "M":
            return 900
    else:
        return r_to_i_dict[char_0]


def roman_numeral_checker(string):
    is_roman_numeral = True
    characters_left = len(string)
    while is_roman_numeral and characters_left > 0:
        for character in string:
            if character not in romanToIntDictionary.keys():
                is_roman_numeral = False
            characters_left -= 1
    if not is_roman_numeral:
        return False
    if is_roman_numeral:
        return True


string_from_user = (input("Enter a roman numeral to convert: ")).upper()
convert_roman_to_int(string_from_user, roman_numeral_checker(string_from_user))
```

Comment: This statement: `char_1 == "V" or "X"` doesn't do what you think it does. `print('c' == 'V' or 'X')` prints `True`

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22304500/7867968) for more information

Comment: @C.Nivs It prints out `X`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is in your boolean logic:

```py
value = 'c'

print(value == 'X' or 'V')
'V'
```

This is because `'V'` is a "truthy" value:

```py
bool('V')
True
```

So you are saying `if value == 'X' or True:` which will *always* be `True`. Because of this, there's an `else` that isn't evaluating:

```py
if value == 'X' or 'V':
    if value == 'X':
        print('X!')
    elif value == 'V':
        print('V!')
    else:
        print('unexpected')

unexpected
```

The correct syntax is:

```py
if value == 'X' or value == 'V':
```

Or even more succinctly:

```py
if value in ('X', 'V'):
    if value == 'X':
        do something
    else:
        do something
```

The else ensures that all cases are covered, and they are, because `value` could only be 'X' or 'V'.

So your whole math logic function would be:

```py
def math_logic(char_0, char_1, r_to_i_dict):
    if char_0 == "I" and char_1 in ('V', 'X'):
        if char_1 == "V":
            return 4
        else:
            return 9
    elif char_1 in ('L', 'C') and char_0 == "X":
        if char_1 == "L":
            return 40
        else:
            return 90
    elif char_1 in ('D', 'M') and char_0 == "C":
        if char_1 == "D":
            return 400
        else:
            return 900
    else:
        return r_to_i_dict[char_0]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. 

In the line `if value == 'X' or True:`, if `'V'` is a "truthy" value and evaluates to true why is `'X'` also not a "truthy" value?

Comment: `X` would if your statement read `if 'X':`, but because you are using a comparison operator `==`, that doesn't apply. `value == 'X'` is a full statement here.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, the first item `'X'` consumes the `value ==` part of the code and equates to that be true or false (in this case, false). All that is left is `if 'V':` which is like saying `bool('V')` and equates to true. That's why the code underneath the `if` statement executes. Thanks dude!